# How to accept a generic collection that works with both `for a in &coll` AND `for a in coll`

Tags: rust, lifetime

This is for hobby/learning purposes. I'm trying to roll my own implementation of a [Centered Interval Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Centered_interval_tree) - I wanted to make a `From<C>` for my `IntervalTree` struct, where `C` is some generic "iterable" collection.

In order to do that, I have two main steps:

1. Do `for a in &coll` to compute the "center"
2. Do a `for a in coll` to consume the collection and build the tree

It seems like I need two type bounds for the `C`:

```rust
C: IntoIterator<Item = A>,
&C: IntoIterator<Item = &A>
```

After following advice from the compiler, I've got lifetime bounds littered all over the place and have arrived at an error I don't understand how to resolve:

```rust
fn iter_twice<'a, C: 'a, A: 'a>(coll: C)
    where &'a C : IntoIterator<Item = &'a A>,
    C: IntoIterator<Item = A>
{
    for a in &coll {
        // ...
    }

    for a in coll {
        // ...
    }

    todo!()
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `coll` does not live long enough
  --> src\itree.rs:57:14
   |
53 | fn iter_twice<'a, C: 'a, A: 'a>(coll: C)
   |               -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
57 |     for a in &coll {
   |              ^^^^^
   |              |
   |              borrowed value does not live long enough
   |              argument requires that `coll` is borrowed for `'a`
...
66 | }
   | - `coll` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I could make my life easier by just accepting `Vec<A>`, but since this is "just for fun" I figured I'd try to make things work with type-generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you used a generic lifetime, the caller needs to choose it. But the lifetime the caller will choose does not necessarily match the lifetime of `coll` (in fact, it can never match it), and this is the error.

What you want is [Higher-Ranked Trait Bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html), meaning `Iterator` is implemented for *every* lifetime:

```rust
fn iter_twice<C, A>(coll: C)
where
    for<'a> &'a C: IntoIterator<Item = &'a A>,
    C: IntoIterator<Item = A>,
{
    // ...
}
```